# Open activity from Notification

Tags: android

When my application is run in background I can able to show the notification by using NotificationManager. When  application is running in foreground if user tries to open the notification which is in the status bar I  need to block the activity open proecss. Because of that currently running activity is affected. So I don't want to open the new activity... Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

you can navigate to any activity by using notifications as by using below code

```
Intent notifyIntent;
notifyIntent = new Intent(activityA.this,activityB.class);
PendingIntent intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(punchclock.this, 0,notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have already gave notification related details on this given link .. may be this will helps you .. [How to execute a method by clicking a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270898/android-how-to-execute-a-method-by-clicking-a-notification/11271367#11271367)

Answer (score 0):

When you call mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification); in your service/activity from where you are showing notification pass Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this); to your pending intent if your activity is opened.
Else pass Intent for the activity to open it.