# Perform Action On Button Click in Custom Notification : Android

Tags: android, onclick, android-notifications

I am trying to perform some action like pause music , play music on button click of a custom notification in android.
Currently I am doing it in this way ,

```
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.layout);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "Custom notification");
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pIntent);
    notification.contentView = contentView;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

But this one takes me to another activity.
Is there anyway to implement notification action on the same activity.

for example.. let's say i raise a notifcation, and when the user press on it, then instead of take me to some activity, it invoke some regular method in my current activity/service

Comment: I have given an answer for the same on given link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270898/how-to-execute-a-method-by-clicking-a-notification/11271367#11271367

Answer (score 12):

First of All assign a intent to your buttons:

```
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.player_notify_layout);
    Intent buttonsIntent = new Intent(context, NotifyActivityHandler.class);
    buttonsIntent.putExtra("do_action", "play");
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgPlayPause, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, buttonsIntent, 0));
```

Then create an activity to handle every action that occurred by notification:

```
    public class NotifyActivityHandler extends Activity {
           public static final String PERFORM_NOTIFICATION_BUTTON = "perform_notification_button";
           
           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

               String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("do_action");
               if (action != null) {
                   if (action.equals("play")) {
                       // for example play a music
                   } else if (action.equals("close")) {
                       // close current notification
                   }
               }

               finish();
         }
    }
```

Finally, you should define activity in **AndroidManifest.xml**. Also you can check this [link](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/AndroidProject_Shortcuts).

Comment: I implemented this solution but setOnClickPendingIntent is not working for me, is there any solution for this?