# Get the PendingIntent event when notification is clicked

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get the event click when a notification is clicked.

### What I have

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
String MyText = "Test";
Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_template_icon_bg, MyText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
String MyNotificationTitle = "Test!";
String MyNotificationText  = "Test!";
Intent MyIntent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);
PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
makeToast(StartIntent.getIntentSender().toString());
mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, StartIntent);
notificationManager.notify( NOTIFY_ME_ID, mNotification);
```

This is working perfect, but the thing that I don't know how to do is get the click on that notification.

### What I've tried

I tried to do something on `onUserInteraction()` that if I'm not wrong seems to get fired when Intent starts a new activity, but didn't work.

Also I've tried on `onActivityResult()` but I don't know how to get that current Intent.

And the last thing that I've tried is doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11271367/4385913)

```
BroadcastReceiver call_method = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String action_name = intent.getAction();
            if (action_name.equals("MyIntent")) {
                //STUFF HERE
            }
   };
};
registerReceiver(call_method, new IntentFilter("MyIntent"));
```

Also instead of put `MyIntent` that is the `Intent`, I've tried to put the `PendingIntent` but doesn't work.

By the way on my code appears this when I try to create a `Notification`

[image]

And this when I try to call the `setLatestEventInfo()`

[image]

But I don't know if it may be the cause of the problem or if it could bring problems in the future.

What I'm doing wrong?

### EDIT

I've just created a sample what my app does at the moment. It's simple when I press a `Button` it pop ups a `Notification`. On my real APP I don't have to click a `Button` but it's the same. The thing that I want is get the event of the click on the `Notification` and make things with that event. The thing that I've done is create another `Activity` where I put the things that I want and then on `onCreate()` at the end of the things that I want to do I call `Finish()` method to finish that `Activity`, but I don't know if it's the best approach. **I want another way to do it I don't want to use two `Activities`...**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btnoti;
private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1337;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnoti = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnoti);
    btnoti.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnoti){
        addNotification();
    }
}

private void addNotification() {

    //We get a reference to the NotificationManager
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String MyText = "Test";
    Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, MyText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
    String MyNotificationTitle = "Test!";
    String MyNotificationText  = "Test!";
    Intent MyIntent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);

    PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, StartIntent);
    notificationManager.notify( NOTIFY_ME_ID, mNotification);
}
```

### Edit 2 (Three fast questions) to go ahead with my code...

I hope you don't mind to solve to me that three fast questions...

1. Since now I've used `Thread.sleep()` to do a task for example every 30 seconds with a `while(true)` but I don't know if it's the best way because I want to let the user choose the time, for example time could be 5 min or 5h... And I don't know what's the best way to take, I've read that theres a method or something called `AlarmManager` is the correct way to repeat tasks? Is there any source sample to know how to use this `Alarm Manager`?
2. I've to know when the user make a "`finish()`" from the `Intent` (ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK) I mean when I'm back to my APP after close that `Intent` I've have used `onResume()` but I don't know if it's the correct way to work with, isn't it? (If you don't understand what I'm traying to say it's simple, I want to know the name of the event that know when the user closes the Wifi network picker)
3. Is this a way to make your APP that still alive once you go to another APP? I mean you can go to another APP and your APP is still working without user interact? Because since now, If I go to another APP my app is like sleep or something and doesn't keep running.... 
   I've read something to call the tasks with a `Service` and I think it goes well, and it still running even if the APP isn't in the Recent APP...

Thanks, if you can't answer me I can make a post for each question but I think those question could be fast to answer.

Comment: Please send me a reminder tomorrow for this ... :)

Comment: Okay master good night :)

Comment: @Y.S. Did you check the question?

Comment: Yes ... will get back to this soon :)

Comment: Okay I'm searching too :D

Comment: Please post ALL the code you have used ... thanks :)

Comment: I've deleted my answer than. Though I still think an activity would be ok. But maybe try pendingintent.getservice as you already stated out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when we start an `Activity` from a push notification, the `Intent` is recovered in the started `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method.

In your case, you are starting a system-defined `Activity` using the `WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK` action. We do not have access to the `onCreate()` of this `Activity`, so it doesn't seem possible to recover the `Intent` from it.

Because you have created a `PendingIntent` using `getActivity()`, its not possible to intercept the `Intent` using a `BroadcastReceiver`. A `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered by a `PendingIntent` created using `getBroadcast()`.

Also, it is  most certainly wrong to use a `PendingIntent` in place of an `Intent` (or vice-versa). These two are not really objects of the same *type*. As such they are not interchangeable. If you observe their namespace classification, it is `android.app.PendingIntent` versus `android.content.Intent`.

I know that this is not a "real" answer to your question, but its all I have for now. I will update this answer if I can think of a solution ... Best.

Comment: So I have to use another `Activity` forced? It's not an event or something for the click of notification?... Btw see my edit with three fast question I think you could help me aswell :)

Comment: I think there may be a solution to this question, let me just think about it ... :)

Comment: **1.** I think that using `Thread.sleep()` and `while(true)` is a bad way to do absolutely anything. And yes, `AlarmManager` is indeed the way to go for repeating tasks. There are any number of examples for this ...

Comment: **2.** You'd have to use `startActivityForResult()`, but I don't know how that's achievable from a notification or through a `PendingIntent`.

Comment: **3.** As you rightly said, `Service` is the correct approach. It is for long-running tasks that don't require user interaction ... :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast answer, Ill search about alarm manager and stuff :) and about onActivityResult for a pendingIntent, also I'll search a bit more about this current question and if I dont find nothing new I'll do what you say ^^