# Execute an action on notification click

Tags: android

I have an application which uses a persistent notification within a service and runs in the background. While this service is running, I need to be able to call a method/do some action when the notification is clicked. However, I'm not sure how to implement this. **I have read through many similar questions/answers, however none were answered clearly or suitably to my purposes.** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270898/how-to-execute-a-method-by-clicking-a-notification) SO questions comes close to what I am trying to achieve, but the chosen answer is hard to understand.

My service/notification is started in the onCreate() method for my BackgroundService class...

```
Notification notification = new Notification();
    startForeground(1, notification);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

and this service is launched from my main activity's button click:

```
final Intent service = new Intent(Main.this, BackgroundService.class);

bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if((counter % 2) == 0){

                bStart.setText("STOP");
                startService(service);

            }else {
                bStart.setText("BEGIN");
                stopService(service);
            }

            counter++;

        }
```

any advice is appreciated

Comment: Could you post your Service class? Preferably with my answer implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use a `BroadcastReceiver` for that. Take a look at the following code. Put it in your `Service`

```
private MyBroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
@Override
onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    // set the custom action
    intentFilter.addAction("do_something");

    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}



// While making notification
Intent i = new Intent("do_something");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;




public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            switch(action) {
                case "do_something":
                    doSomething();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

public void doSomething() {
    //Whatever you wanna do on notification click
}
```

This way the `doSomething()` method will be called when your `Notification` is clicked.

Comment: this did not work. I put a log in the onReceive() method instead of the placeholder method (doSomething()), but I didnt get any response after clicking the notification

Comment: @Steve At this point, I would ask myself, is the Receiver registered properly? Is the notification.contentIntent set properly, at the right place in your code?

Comment: everything is setup in the correct place. Notification started in onCreate() method, receiver is registered there as well

Comment: @Steve You should put the line **notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;** before **startForeground(1, notification);**