# Get click event on Notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a notification that opens a url. So far, so good. Now I need to do some things when the notification is clicked, even when the application is in the background or killed.
Here is my code to generate notify:

```
val intent: Intent =
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri).apply {
                flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            }
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, pushIntent, 0)
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id_channel)
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
  .setContentTitle(title)
  .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
  .setAutoCancel(false)
pendingIntent.setContentIntent(intent)
with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
  notify(id, builder.build())
}
```

thanks...

Comment: Did you saw this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32257517/11538132 ?

Comment: @Kamil this solution delete extras from intent