# Notification Buttons clicks not working

Tags: android, notifications

I have setup a Notification for my app and the code goes like this :

```
public int getNotification( View view) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity() ,RouteMap.class );
        intent.putExtra("Stop Ride",true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0) ;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getToast("API below 16 ...notification not supported");

        } else {

            Notification notify = new Notification.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon1)
                    .setContentTitle("Car Rental")
                    .setContentText("Click to view ")
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon3,"View ",pendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.alert_icon,"Stop Ride", pendingIntent )
                    .build();

            notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notify);

        }

        return notificationID;
    }

    public void removeNotification() {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(
                notificationID);
        getToast("Notification Removed");
    }
```

the app show the notification but does not perform any action when buttons on notification are clicked 
please help me if something is to be added to my code .

**Update :**
As This method is inside a fragment class

I have changed some of my code as suggested below but it didnt work :

```
 public int getNotification( View view) {

   // NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RouteMap.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getToast("API below 16 ...notification not supported");

    } else {

        Notification notify = new Notification.Builder(getActivity())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon12)
                .setContentTitle("Car Rental")
                .setContentText("Click to view ")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon3, "View ", pendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.alert_icon, "Stop Ride", pendingIntent)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notify);

    }

    return notificationID;
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270898/how-to-execute-a-method-by-clicking-a-notification) out.

Answer (score 0):

this what i use in my app.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, NotifReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, notifNum, i, 0);

        Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
                .setContentTitle("MyPower Reminder")

                .setContentText(contentTxt)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mypower4)
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setSound(notifSound)

                //.addAction(0, "View Full Reminder", pi)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notifMgr = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifMgr.notify(0, notif);
```

.addAction(0, "View Full Reminder", pi) also works like clicking the notification. it appears like a button with your set text. so i don't use, i like preserving my codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code It may be work for you.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("App Name")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setSound(soundUri); //This sets the sound to play
            notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: what was the problem ?

Comment: the notification buttons are not working when click , they dont open any intents or pending intents..

Comment: please set context on position of this in intent and pending intent and try

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); like

Comment: Context context = getActivity();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RouteMap.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);