# calling a method in service after click on notification

Tags: android, notifications

i have a notification which i'm calling from a service. I want to call the service again on notification click. But the notification click is not able to get inside the method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class).setAction(ACTION_1);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.food)
                    .setContentTitle("notification")
                    .setContentText("near by you!");
   NotificationManager mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Method that i want to call is

```
if (ACTION_1.equals(resultPendingIntent)) {
        getRecommendation();
    } 
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```

i have tried following link but not able to resolve my problem.
 [How to execute a method by clicking a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270898/how-to-execute-a-method-by-clicking-a-notification)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify a `Broadcast` in your `Service` and launch that via a `PendingIntent` in your notification.

```
Intent stopIntent = new Intent("my.awersome.string.name");
PendingIntent stopPi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 4, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Then, in your notification builder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    ...     
    .setContentIntent(stopPi);
```

In your `Service` you can setup a `BroadcastReceiver` as:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Code to run
    }
};
```

You register this `receiver` in your `Service` (possibly in `onStartCommand()`) only using:

```
registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("my.awersome.string.name"));
```

Your `Service` MUST be running for this to work.

Comment: You are a life saver. This is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm. Thanks!!

Comment: where to setup Broadcast in service

Comment: @VipulChauhan You can set it up as soon as you launch the notification but, make sure that you unregister it as soon as you're done with it (and also in onDestroy())

Comment: thanks for your fast reply but i already done with it now i am stuck with how to set custom layout for notification

Comment: @VipulChauhan thats an entirely different problem. You can try finding a solution on SO or create a new issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to try [How to execute a method by clicking a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270898/how-to-execute-a-method-by-clicking-a-notification) ..but be careful because of the static class