# how can i add action event on notification action

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, alarm

I want to stop mediaplayer and cancel the notification when i click on stop action of notification

this is my alarm function

```
public void alarmstart(String idd,int alarmmonth,int alarmyear,int alarmday,int alarmhour,int alarmmin)
    {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        myIntent = new Intent(Create.this,AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("title",tii);
        myIntent.putExtra("note",noo);
        myIntent.putExtra("id",id);
        pendingIntent = 
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,Integer.valueOf(idd),myIntent,0);


        Calendar cal1=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH,alarmmonth-1);
        cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR,alarmyear);
        cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,alarmday);

        cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,alarmhour);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE,alarmmin);
        cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal1.getTimeInMillis() ,pendingIntent);


    }
```

this is my notification class broadcast receiver

```
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    PendingIntent pintent;
    static String id;



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        String ti,no;
        ti=intent.getExtras().getString("title");
        no=intent.getExtras().getString("note");
        id=intent.getExtras().getString("id");



        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(ti)
                .setContentText(no)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .addAction(new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.mipmap.stop,
                        "Stop",
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)))


                .setContentInfo("Info");
          mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.teri);
         mMediaPlayer.start();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Integer.valueOf(id),builder.build());


    }


}
```

please can anyone help me on this I am newbie on this almost read the all previous posts related to this topic but not able to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use IntentService in AlarmNotificationReceiver class and handle mMediaPlayer object for stop , pause , play or anything else that you want to do ,the same as following code :

```
  public static class NotificationActionService extends IntentService {
    public NotificationActionService() {
        super(NotificationActionService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if ("StopSound".equals(action)) {
            // TODO: handle action StopSound.
           mMediaPlayer.stop();
            // If you want to cancel the notification: 
   NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
   // NOTIFICATION_ID : you can (set and get) notificationid (to/from) intent 
        }
    }
```

in onReceive method of AlarmNotificationReceiver you should set intent and call  NotificationActionService

```
 Intent stopSoundIntent = new Intent(context, 
 NotificationActionService.class)
        .setAction("StopSound");

    PendingIntent stopSoundPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            stopSoundIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Sample Notification")
                    .setContentText("Notification text goes here")
                    .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                            "StopSound", stopSoundPendingIntent));

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

you can edit this solution according to what you need.

i hope this solution be benefit for you.

for more detail you can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270898/how-to-execute-a-method-by-clicking-a-notification)

Comment: thanks bro that helped and how to open activity on clicking on the notification and is there any method to know when the notification are cleared so i can also stop the media player on notification clear